# can i display excel and word document from base64 encoded data to webpage?

Tags: php, html, object-tag

I am developing one application in php zend framework.

I have so many documents which are in base64 encoded string.

Can i display that document on my php webpage using object tag or embed tag or by using any other method ?

I am using following code to display pdf documents and images :

```
For PDFs :
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo $documentdata; ?>"></embed>
For Images :
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="image/jpeg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $vv['OLEObject']; ?>"></embed>
```

But its not working for word document and excel document using type 'application/msword' and 'application/vnd.ms-excel' respectively.

Does anyone know how to do ?

Comment: DID you find an answer to it? I need to show xls files base 64 encoded too

Answer (score 0):

Are you using embed for the word docs as well? Try using object as below:

```
<object data="file:///C|/myfile.doc" type="application/msword" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></object>
```

Comment: But i dont have physical file. I have document in base64 encoded string. how to give base64 data to object ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for display base64 world content to html preview.
but you can only download.